# vim copy/yank without leaving visual mode

Tags: vim

In normal text edit after I select and copy, the selection stays still, so I can copy again quickly. But in vim when I press y in visual mode, I enter normal mode, so I need to select again. I want a quicker way.

Reasons:
When testing a console app, I copy test data from text editor and paste  into console. Then I find bugs and edit code, the clipboard may change and I need to copy and paste test data to test again

Comment: Not answering your question but possibly solving your problem, you could also possibly send that test data into your app directly with `./my_app < test_data.txt`. Alternatively, make you application able to read data from files directly, then you can just launch the app over and over again with fewer keystrokes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can reselect last visual region typing `gv`

```
                        *gv* *v_gv* *reselect-Visual*
gv          Start Visual mode with the same area as the previous
            area and the same mode.
            In Visual mode the current and the previous Visual
            area are exchanged.
            After using "p" or "P" in Visual mode the text that
            was put will be selected.
```

Comment: really helpful! I add `vmap <C-c> ygv`, this works just like normal editor

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to be in visual mode in order to yank text. While in normal mode, the yank command can be combined with a motion: `y{motion}`. You can read more about that here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip312#Copying_and_cutting_in_normal_mode

It also sounds like you would like to yank text into the system clipboard. On most Linux distributions, you can do this by yanking text into the `+` register. Depending on the distro, you may need to install `gvim`.